# if a member.activity == xxxx do something,, Can i do this?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i want, if a member activity name == Visual Studio Code, do something

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def task_loop():
    channel = bot.get_channel(1120312276579266590)
    for member in bot.guilds[0].members:
     if member.activity == discord.Activity(name='Visual Studio Code'):
        await channel.send(member.mention)
        await channel.send(member.activity)
```

i tried

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def task_loop():
    channel = bot.get_channel(1120312276579266590)
    for member in bot.guilds[0].members:
     if member.activity == discord.ActivityType.playing:
        await channel.send(member.mention)
        await channel.send(member.activity)
```

but not working

Comment: Did you enable the required intents?

Comment: yes ```intents = discord.Intents.all()```

Answer (score 1):

Just like the logic you stated, "if a member activity name == Visual Studio Code". You can use the attribute `name`.

```py
@bot.command(name='test')
async def test(ctx):
  if ctx.author.activity.name == 'Visual Studio Code':
    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.name} is on Visual Studio Code')
```

Documentation: [discord.Activity](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?#discord.Activity)

Comment: i want ```"if a member activity name == Visual Studio Code"``` in task.loop or on_presense_update

Comment: It's the same logic, you get the `member` object from `for member in bot.guilds[0].members:` then check if the `member.activity.name` is equal to Visual Studio Code

Comment: ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'``` It gives this error for ```member.activity.name```

Comment: This is a separate issue. `bot.guilds` returns a `SequenceProxy`, convert it to a list to be able to index it with `[0]`. Also, I don't get why you can't just get the guild object with `bot.get_guild(id, /)` since you're already getting the channel with `bot.get_channel`

Comment: ```@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def task_loop():
    channel = bot.get_channel(1120312276579266590)
    for member in bot.guilds[0].members:
     if member.activity == discord.Activity(application_id=383226320970055681):
      await channel.send(member.activity)```
i try it, but not working.

Comment: ```if member.activity == discord.CustomActivity(name='ssss'):
      await channel.send(member.activity)```
but i use this, and it's WORKING